# Can the optimizer reorder a drop call to before the variable appears to go out of scope?

Tags: rust, scope, drop

For example

```
fn thing(&self, other: OtherThing) {
    {
        let me = self.lock.lock().unwrap();
        ...
        me.do_something(); // last use of me

        // me does not NEED to exist here

        other.callfunc();
    }
}
```

In this case, in C++, where I draw my experience from, the `me` lock will be locked until after `other.callfunc()` happens. The variable doesn't go out of scope and call the destructor until the closing brace of the scope definition.

In Rust, I know the borrow checker has the ability to notice that where it says "me does not NEED to exist" it can mark `me` as not borrowed and allow somebody else to borrow it. Does that hold true for the optimizer also?

Is it possible that the compiler will call the implicit `drop` before `other.callfunc()`, or is that impossible by language design?

I couldn't find any documentation that clears this up so I can be absolutely sure.

Comment: tl;dr the duplicate: no. Borrow lifetimes do not affect drop order, or codegen at all, really.